# Set CORS headers with ImageResizer

Tags: c#, .net, cors, imageresizer

Is it possible to reply with the correct headers for CORS requests when using [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/) directly as a pipeline on IIS?

Using the RemoteReader plugin and sending an OPTIONS request also results in ImageResizer sending the resized image right away instead of waiting for the GET.

```
/remote.jpg.ashx?urlb64=...&hmac=P0E_Dl0Ill0&width=300
```

I know this is usually not a problem when loading images through an image-tag, but I have the scenario where a browser-based client needs to store binary data directly and uses javascript's `XmlHttpRequest` to do so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [plugin development](http://imageresizing.net/docs/extend/basics) for ImageResizer, it shouldn't be hard to implement plugin that adds CORS headers.